# What is the purpose of currency field under property set up in Google Analytics

Tags: google-analytics, seo, google-analytics-api

There is a currency field under property set up in Google Analytics. What purpose does it serves? The reporting time zone perhaps shows the website visits and other stats based on that specific time zone but what role does the currency field plays.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

GA does not only track hits, sessions and users. It also tracks so-called E-commerce events. When something is added to cart, removed from it, various checkout steps, purchases, refunds and many more. To measure them more precisely, GA offers to track a few monetary metrics that are measured in currency.

That currency will be mostly used in e-commerce reports. You can read more on it here: https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/6205902?hl=en#zippy=%2Cin-this-article